# Several comma separated calls in one row in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, syntax

Lately, I saw the following line:

```
[someObject release], someObject = nil;
```

Why does this work? Why and under which circumstances can there be several calls separated by `,` in one row? (**Not** `;`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objective C is a superset of C, and `,` is an *operator* in C. It evaluates to the last expression in the chain, and creates a [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).

Semicolon `;` cannot be used in an expression because it is not an operator.

You may have seen the `,` operator at work in a more common situation that involves `for` loops:

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
for ( ; i < 200 ; i++, j += 3) { // This is one of the more typical uses of ','
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) evaluates the first operand and discards the result, then evaluates the second and returns its value. The first has no return value, and the second has a return value of `nil` in this case.